# How to use designated init with nested struct in C?

Tags: c, struct, initialization

I am trying to create a Node struct which points to another Node of the same type.

My struct looks like this:

```
typedef struct Node {
    int value;
    struct Node *next;
} Node;
```

I can initialize it using normal malloc and assigning the properties of the struct like so:

```
Node *top = malloc(sizeof(Node));
top->value = 1;
top->next = NULL;
```

But it fails if I try to use a designated init with the struct.

```
Node *next = {.value = 2, .next = {NULL, NULL}}; // warning: excess elements in scalar initializer
```

I have also tired:

```
Node *next = {2, NULL}; // incompatible integer to pointer conversion initializing 'Node *'
Node *next = {NULL, 2}; // excess elements in scalar initializer
```

The only init that work is just assigning it all to zero

```
Node *next = {0}; // no error
```

To compile I am using the following command

```
gcc -Wall foo.c -o foo
```

Comment: Because a pointer is not a `struct`. Use a compound literal (actually the pointer to one).

Comment: ***If*** local storage us acceptable  (which it's probably not), look into "compound literal" syntax. Otherwise, you need to `malloc` and can't do that in a designated initializer.

Comment: `Node *next = ...` does not initialize `*next` but only `next`.

Comment: `next` is a __pointer__, therefore the only thing that makes sense is  `Node *next = NULL`;

Comment: In case it was not clear: You don't have a nested `struct`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can construct a list statically like this:

```
Node node2 = { .value = 2, .next = NULL };
Node node1 = { .value = 1, .next = &node2 };
Node *first = &node1;
```

If using automatic storage class for the nodes, make sure you never use them after the end of the enclosing block is reached, as they will no longer be valid.

Answer (score 0):

After allocating the memory, you can use a compound literal to set the fields:

```
Node *p = malloc(sizeof(Node));
if (!p) {
    perror("malloc failed");
    exit(1);
}
*p = (Node){ .value = 1, .next = NULL };
```

Comment: OP apparently wants an initialiser.